# ClassNotFoundException while implementing a web client

Tags: java, web-services, webservice-client, jersey-client

I'm implemeting a webclient to consume a RESTful webserv using a POST call.

I'm using Jersey API for it.

```
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;

public class MyJerseyClient {
  public void updateGame(String url) {
        Client client = Client.create();
        WebResource webResource = client.resource(url);

    ClientResponse response = webResource.type("application/json").post(ClientResponse.class);
    if (response.getStatus() != 200) {
        System.out.println("o/p >>  ERROR!!");
    } else {
        System.out.println(response.getEntity(String.class););
    }
  } 
}
```

I've imported external jars using Project > Properties > Java Build Path > Add External Jars.  [image]

But still getting an error -

[image]

[image]

Can someone please point me what I might be missing here?

Comment: How are you running this code? From inside eclipse with Tomcat in it or with a standalone tomcat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the required `jersey-client` JAR file is in your build path, it doesnt appear to be on your client's runtime classpath.

Comment: How to add jars to runtime classpath?

Comment: i have a standalone tomcat server which i run using startup.bat, Should i be copying those files in tomcats lib directory?

Comment: That's not absolutely necessary (or even advisable). If the application is a part of a deployed web application then ensure the JAR is deployed to `WEB-INF/classes`

Comment: Got it! Appreciate your inputs.